# Get result from register r0 in C++(arm instruction set)

Tags: c++, assembly, arm

I need to get value from register r0, after arm instructor was executed.

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL test(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{

     /* execute arm instructions code,the result has been stored in register r0 */
     ......

     /* get result from register r0 */
     int result = 0;
     __asm __volatile(
     "mov %0,r0/n"
        :"=r"(result)
        :
        :
        );

     /* return value according to result */
}
```

but I got compiler error like as follows:

```
Error: garbage following instruction -- `mov r2,r0/n'
```

With the help of Bo Persson, I fixed compiler errors by change "/n" to "\n". But I get a strange number -1449926 from result. The expected result should be 1 or 10.

After debugging with IDA pro, the register r0 has the right number. I think I have some problems for passing the value from r0 to the variable result. I want to know how to get value from register r0 and store it with result.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\n`?

Comment: @Bo Persson  Thank you very much!

Comment: should it be the other order "mov r0, #0", also take note that you don't need \n

Comment: @Krypton thanks for your answer, but I still get 0 from result after I change the statement  to " mov r0, #0" or "".

Comment: Not inline assembler pro, but you could try something like `register int r0 __asm__("r0");
  return r0;`

Comment: @ttdado, thanks for your answer. I had found the result that caused errors.  The result from r0 was overwritten by function call. I get the right result by change the function declaration from void(*)(void*) to int(*)(void*)